C++ and memory safety
At my tiny org, the core engine is C++ due to a compute heavy workload. I need to internally react to NSA's recommendation about replacing C++ with a memory safe language.
They're highlighting the fact that C++ (or C) allows the code to read from or write to any memory address (i.e. pointers). That can lead to bugs like read / write out of bounds, or read / write after delete (dangling pointers). These bugs can then be exploited in production by malicious actors.
I don't think my org can afford to rewrite the codebase in another language in near to medium term, and I am not even sure we need to. As long as we do the following in our codebase, can we claim memory safety? (for the purpose of this question, I want to ignore any other kinds of safety or good coding practices).

No heap allocation ourselves. No new / delete
No char* for string variables, only std::string
Replace static arrays with std::array, dynamic arrays with std::vector
No pointers. Pass objects by reference where needed

Anything else?
Edits based on comments received
6/14/24: The code is not running in a highly resource constrained environment like an embedded system. Nor is it super sensitive where failure could harm someone's health or well being
6/14/24: We use Visual Studio and GCC as our compilers. To the extent the compilers would catch something, I don't want to repeat it in our internal guidelines
6/17/24: Safety seems to mean different things to different people. In the context of this question (and NSA's paper), a bug introduced by lack of memory safety is harmful because it can be exploited by malicious actors. Think heart bleed or Morris worm where buffer overflow had a role to play. A program crashing is not the same thing as a program being tricked to do something it wasn't supposed to do (using heart bleed as an example, I would rather have it crash than leak credentials)
6/17/24: The fact that this question is about memory safety, doesn't mean that we don't care about other kinds of safety
6/17/24: Google's Safer Usage of C++ comes quite close to describing both the problems and potential solutions that I am grappling with.

This question requires probably a much longer answer than you thought, and some of our hardliners will surely downvote and close-vote it ("needs more focus"). Still, I like it.

... but to give you a short answer: what you really need is something like the MISRA standard and its extension to C++ mentioned there, but for which I could not find a Wikipedia article on its own.

C++ code is pretty memory safe assuming you stick to RAII and use features like vector, shared_ptr, const arguments. Most OSes now protect against buffer overrun. Linking against up to date os components goes a long way to help your code.

Of course its possible to write memory-safe C++ code, you just can't prove that the code is safe using the type system. You can use the type system + linters + sanitizers + fuzzing to reduce the likelihood of memory safety issues. One thing that you're missing is that the smart pointers can still be nullptr, and that vector doesn't do bounds checks. I wouldn't think about rewriting, but about adopting security-conscious modern C++ practices, and about investigating safer languages for future components.

"I need to internally react" Can you elaborate on this? Is just this someone (non-technical?) within your org who read this and is now asking for some remediation? Or is there some specific 'real' outcome if you can't address this e.g., regulatory, lost business?

@JimmyJames. You're right, the remediation needs to make sense to a non-technical audience. There is no immediate consequence of non-compliance, but it can be at some point in future.

Rule 2 is a subset of rule 4, since char pointers are form of pointer. Likewise a strict reading of 4 implies 1, since new/delete operate on pointers. However that is not sufficient, you also need to ban array access (out of bounds), and any form of storage or return of references. This is very restrictive.

@amon, if we're not going to allocate anything on the heap, we don't need smart pointers, right?

Any program that does something useful and is also readable and maintainable will use heap allocations at some point. Theoretically you can wrap the smart pointers in your own implementation and avoid exposing the methods that return raw pointers. Is this worth your time? You are the only one who can answer this. If this is really going to be a problem, perhaps you should invest time into switching to Rust or something.

If someone nontechnical is feeling alarmed or worried about this report and nobody has identified any specific risks to the business/customers/etc, then it sounds like the most important thing is reassurance, stakeholder management and communication.   You could counter this by pointing out that having a system built around unsafe code doesn't necessarily mean any imminent risk to the business - especially if that code has already proven itself over years.

I wonder if presenting some examples of memory-safety issues from "safe" Rust would alleviate some concerns.

The key think I would make sure the non-technical stakeholders understand is how disastrously bad it will likely go if you attempted to rewrite the entire application in one shot using another language/platform. If it's decided that a rewrite is needed, the first thing to figure out is how you can do it one piece at a time. Otherwise, you need a mitigation strategy. It might need to be someone's job to implement software security practices. There's a lot of information about the things to look out for with C and C++. Largely because there's a lot to look out for.

@Basilevs Can you point to a reference of what some of those are?

@JimmyJames I've added a link to that comment

One consideration I have not seen mentioned is training & code reviews. You want to have processes in place that prevents a single clueless developer from introducing problems without anyone noticing it. Any rules you create will be worthless unless there are also process in place to ensure they are followed.

Whether statements like "our C++ codebase is memory safe" are useful is a discussion for itself. Independent of that, your measures to make C++ memory safe are far from sufficient. Many out-of-bound accesses are hard to prevent by simple rules.
For a std container like a vector or a string v, v[i] may refer to pretty arbitrary memory if i is out of bounds. Such accesses cannot be avoided easily. Is the following code safe?
for (auto& x : v)
{
  foo();
  bar(x);
}

It is not, because foo may access a reference of v and resize it such that it moves in memory. Then, using x afterwards is not safe anymore.
You could route all memory accesses through custom containers where each operation includes a bounds check. Even then, you are not safe if you need to account for multithreading and race conditions. Adding locks everywhere may help with that, but it's probably not worth the cost. It may then be cheaper to switch languages. C++ has many strengths, but they come at a price.
You may want to ask yourself (and the stakeholders) whether 100% memory safety is actually necessary. There are more kinds of attacks that can achieve bad results, so focussing on memory safety is a little bit narrow-sighted.
If you want to stick with C++, I'd recommend to follow best practices and coding guidelines like, for example, the CppCoreGuidelines. Additionally, make use of sanitizers and static code analyzers and add a good test suite. Most importantly, educate your team.

Before you go in deep, look at what “memory safe” in other languages means. A[i] = 0 with out of range i can overwrite a random memory location. Or it can instantly crash your software. Or it can throw an exception that you can catch (and then how are you going to handle that?). The “badness” of what happens is different, but in either case the assignment should have never happened, and the real problem is the assignment.
Comments: Amon seems to be missing the point. Some code is unacceptable. And in a “memory safe” language most of it is just as unacceptable. Discussing which is worse is pointless when it is unacceptable either way.

I don't think this is a helpful take. Memory-safe languages don't magically make code correct, you're right on that. But "the program is guaranteed to crash" is much safer than UB, and at least gives you a decent chance to notice the problem.

“Guaranteed to crash” is in many situations unacceptable. Just like undefined behaviour, which in many cases is exactly the same.

@amon is correct to point out, that UB is less acceptable than crash. UB is much more dangerous specifically because it sometimes does not lead to crash. In other words, there are a lot of situations where crash is acceptable while UB is not.

If safety is so important for OP,  UB and crash are probably equally bad

What is worse sort of depends, a crash may also give worse outcome than UB. Consider Ariane 5 - instead of getting undefined values for a float to short integer conversion the program crashed, and brought the rocket down with it. But in general they are "equally bad" (or at least unacceptably bad) in critical situations.

UB is much worse than crash. Consider reading data out of an array's range by mistake. Typically it won't crash, since there is some data there, often accessible to the process. This might even pass tests, and yet it may have a very unexpected and unwanted behaviour in production. And this particular example is a source of insane number of security vulnerabilities.

INT_MAX+1 in C or C++ produces INT_MIN on many machines without crashing and the application works just fine. Or testing would have found a problem. So better than a crash.

@gnasher729 you're right that signed integer overflow works like that on many machines. What UB means is that it might do something completely different at any unpredictable time. Including crashing right there, or producing almost correct results until crashing at some unpredictable time later. Have fun debugging the latter one.

@gnasher729 concrete behaviour of integer overflow depends on its representation. I'm pretty sure almost all, if not all, modern cpus use two's complement representation. And therefore the behaviour is de facto well defined. To the point that other languages (e.g. Rust) make it standard. C/C++ doesn't only for historical reasons.

Memory safety in C++
You can easily write memory safe code in C++ if using some recommended practices such as:

avoiding raw arrays and prefering vectors
avoid raw pointers and prefer smart pointers
if using const and const references whenever possible
and a few more, like the enforcement of the rule of 3.

The NSA's prudent position is that nothing would prevent someone from using a rogue pointer, or use a reference to an object that lifetime has passed away (for example using it in some lambda, or threaded code). But good and simple coding standards, such as the C++ core guidelines, prevent most of issues here.
Safety is made by people and requires some discipline
My whole point here is that languages are only a part of the system safety. Of course, they can facilitate some practices or give visibility to insecure constructs.  But ultimately, people are at the core of safety, and some discipline is required.
For example, there are several standards to strengthen further code written by large teams when developing mission critical systems in C++, such as:

Google's safer usage of C++
Lockheed's Martin's the JSF-AV Joint Strike Fighter - Air Vehicle C++ Coding Standards (from 2005, i.e. predates modern C++11) (probably used for the development of the F-35's software which largely relies on a C/C++ code base)
Autosar's Guidelines for the use of the C++14 language in critical and safety-related systems very popular in the automotive industry (google for it)
or Carnegie Mellon's SEI CERT C++ Coding Standard.

As a counter example,  the nicest languages are not exempt of vulnerabilities in the language implementation or from supply-chain attacks via vulnerable popular components that hide insecure features:

Carnegie Mellon's SEI blog: Recent Rust Vulnerabilities


The lifetime is next to impossible to predict in C++. See answer by @pschill

@Basilevs as long time practitioner having worked with C++ since before templates even existed, and having witnessed the emergence of cleaner ways to do things since modern c++11, I simply do not agree. The main risk with C++ is caused by a lot of teachers around the world who still teach C idioms and malloc() in C++, have not inderstood the C*+ object model and perpetuate UB behaviors and use of raw pointers because they feel powerful in doing so. Such a way of teaching should be considered as a crime.

I have 10 years of experience with C++ and worked professionally with it for 6 years I've hit the UB @pschill describes multiple times and there was nothing I could do to predict it. There are NO raw pointers in his example. The UB is very well hidden. The reference to a vector being updated or iterator over it may be obtained indirectly. I perfectly understand the nature of this particular UB and it does not help a bit.

There are no reliable ways to work with C++. You can only test and do SEGV driven development.

@Basilevs strange that sonfar most of the spacecrafts, rockets, planes, powerplants and life critical systems that cannot bear any interuotions were development in C++.

they can and do test

@Basilev but doesn't everybody do tests, whatever the language? Don't we mix here very different problems ? I mean, you can have a similar code like pschils in lemory safe languages like Swift. You wouldn't have UB but you would not iterate on the latest version of v. If this loops would be to calculate insulin dosage, it could mean life or death even if it's not UB in swift. On the other side you can by design prevent these situations in C++ as well. I use for example a lot copies when there is a risk of conflict.

At the same time C++ offers const functions to prevent accidental changes of an object's state, which is a very common issue in other languages. What I want to say here is that you cannot generalise your own experience. There are a lot of C++ developments that are not al all driven by SEGV. (but hopefully test driven).

That's the problem. It is much harder to design protection against UB than against DB. And all modern languages have const or even value objects, that's a given, not an advantage. Driven or not, safety is never a commodity in C++.

@Christophe most critical systems in spacecrafts, rockets and powerplants are written in Ada, not C++. Precisely because of Ada's safety. C++ is s**t language for masochists. Yes, you can write safe code in it. Except the language itself taunts you to do otherwise. Safe pointers? Sure, except most libs still use raw pointers. Good luck with that, or write everything from scratch.

And tests are only as good as the person writing them is. Which typically means a lot worse than what proper static analyzers can do (I'm thinking about Ada and Rust, C++ cannot be properly analyzed due to its nature). The only reason to use C++ is because of its amazing performance, nothing else.

For example thread safety is notoriously hard to test. That's why languages like Rust heavily restrict what you can and cannot do with respect to threads. C++ does not. Literally no C++ feature helps you writing thread safe code.

@freakish safety requires a constant effort in all languages. I'm pretty sure that deadlocks are possible in Ada, first papers on insecurity of rust start to emerge (attacks via common packages using unsecure features), and whatever language, it's only a matter of time to stumble on some issues (caused by the language or its implementation or a commonly used library: the end result is the same). My message here: ranting on languages has no benefit in safe and secure programming. It's people and engineering discipline that makes the difference.

@Christophe ridiculous. Rust was literally created so that we depend less on people. If a tool can take care of a problem I see no reason to depend on people. And the fact that Rust or Ada also have issues is no argument for using C++. Unless those issues outweight C++ issues.

And at least Rust issues do not outweight C++ issues. There's a reason why it become second language (after C) in Linux kernel development, even though C++ exists for like what? 50 years?

@freakish as said, language war and my-language-is-better-than-yours arguments are not constructive and do not help in solving real word problems.

Is that the thing you say when you run out of arguments? Because there are objectively better and worse languages. Otherwise everyone would still be writing direct machine code, not even assembly. Yes, it does solve real world problems. Again: why do you think Rust was created? For fun?

@freakish your assertion of "objectively better language" is not universal. If you already have 1M lines of C++, it's not better to start from scratch in rust, you will run out of money before you have reimplemented the features you already have, and even if you don't, you'll introduce a whole bunch of new bugs.

@Caleth sure, legacy and technological debt is no joke. And the only real reason we keep using those outdated tech stacks. That being said it is just a matter of time, hopefully. The movement has already started. In fact there's even DARPA project sponsored by the USA government (I think) which aims to translate entire C to Rust. Ambitious? Sure. But the fact that it exists already says much.

@freakish I wouldn't call Unreal Engine legacy tech debt. But using it is one of a small number of options when developing a 3d game to modern standards. I'm not aware of any commercially available game engines in rust or ada.

@Caleth what do you mean by "commercially available" and why does it matter? Rust does have multiple game engines, I've been using one myself: bevy. Free to use and open source, btw. It is not as mature as Unreal Engine, but then again entire Rust isn't. As I said: a matter of time.

@freakish As in, can you as a solo or small team, licence something featureful enough to be able to make your game, not having to write all the physics, graphics, networking, etc yourself. Bonus points for also being able to licence animated 3d models of whatever as 3rd party plugins

@Caleth I don't know much about game development, especially how licencing works (I've been doing some private projects only, for fun), so I can't really say. But for physics, graphics, networking, etc. then yes, Rust has crates (modules) for each, and bevy does come with them out of the box. As far as I'm aware all of that is free to use and modify. Bevy does not have a fancy editor like UE though, but it is on the roadmap AFAIK.

As for 3d models or similar assets, I'm pretty sure these are distributed in a language independent formats. Bevy supports multiple such formats. So you can buy an asset from UE store and use it with bevy, I don't think it is a problem at all. At least technically, UE store might prohibit that, I do not know.

changing the language to make execution "safer" is
probably starting in the wrong place.
(Dumbo the elephant held a feather in his trunk and could fly.
What if the Ringmaster got feathers for all the big elephants
so they could fly too?  Wouldn't work.)
the team should agree on a common understanding of what "safety" is for
their environment and product, and make a plan to provide the safety.
that plan could say that programs have to work differently, and
programmers have to pay attention to certain failure modes, and
maybe use an existing language differently, or use a new language.
then the team can start evaluating how to implement the plan.
